# Error in hist.default(xa) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram

I'm a complete R beginner, and am trying to do something pretty basic - make histograms of two vectors I imported from Excel.

The vectors are xa and xb. I tried hist(xa), and get the following error:

```
Error in hist.default(xa) : 'x' must be numeric
```

So I did some searching, and tried to remedy this using as.numeric(xa), and got:

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So I tried the as.list function, but it turned my vector into a matrix. Not really sure what's going on. The numbers in the vectors are all 4 digits between about -2 and +10. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Given that this is a data problem, post the output from `dput(head(xa))` and `dput(head(xb))`

Answer (score 6):

Here's something you can try... no guarantees, since you have not given a working example:

```
newXa <- sapply(xa, as.numeric)
hist(newXa)
```

What should be done is to look at the structure of 'x'

```
str(x)
```

Then if 'xa' is how you are referring to x[['a']] you would do this:

```
hist( x[['a']] )
```

And if `str(x)` showed that the "a" column were a factor, one might have more success with this:

```
 hist( as.numeric(as.character(x[['a']]))  )
```

Comment: `as.numeric` might have bad effects if a numeric variable has accidentally been converted to a factor ...